# Add ssrs report description

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Anyway I can add a ssrs report description that displays in the report before execution? I Googled and most people said its not possible but there has to be a way to tweak it right?

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who still needs to add a report description that users can read before executing the report, I have seen this feature in both SSRS versions I have used (2008 and 2016).  The Report Properties has a Description field, which users can read when accessing the web portal in either view (Tiles or Details/List).

You administrate the Description field configuration from various locations-- web portal, Report Manager, or Visual Studio.  I prefer Visual Studio for its version control abilities.

**In visual studio...**
With the report open, click in the spaces outside of the report objects (header, tablix, ect).  In the Report Properties window go to Description and enter the description.  Deploy the report.

**In report manager...**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156032(v=sql.120).aspx

**On the report portal...**
Simply go to the report, click manage, properties, description.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to look at Description before you "Deploy" or "Execute" your report.  In your report builder/visual studio (whichever tool you're using), you should be able to `right click` your report and `Go to Code` to see report description if you search for `<Description>` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Description>Executive Reporting</Description>
```

If you do not see it, you can simply insert one.  Reason to set description here instead of Report Manager is re-deploying your report will not overwrite the description since it is already part of your report.  Plus, you get to see it before deploying or executing your report.

Comment: I tried to use this in visual studio to change description of a report and it's not updatin on the server. Any idea why?

Comment: Make sure deploy was successful.  Also, you have to save your changes you make to code.  If you go back to "Code", do you see description you added?  Also, if you have multiple servers, make sure it is being pointed to correct server.

Comment: Sometimes I notice when making changes to the code, I have to either close visual studio and re-open in order to see my changes.  In some rare cases, I would have to delete the report and re-deploy it.  See either of these fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up finding this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/149665/why-does-ssrs-not-update-a-reports-description and using the script https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/198516/132045 had to modify as I made in comment there,

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do to show the report description.

1. Add a `textbox` to your `Report header` and use `expression` to show text in that text box which gives some sort of description.
2. Right Click your data region go to `tablix properties` and there use `Expression in ToolTip` section to show report description. This will be shown when user hover mouse over report.

The reason I have advised to use expressions in your textbox or tooltip is because if report has multiple parameters and you want the report description to be dynamic then you can use expressions to make it dynamic and it will change depending on the values of the parameters.

But if it is a static report which always show same type of data then you can simply use hard coded text in these two places to show the report description.

Comment: When you say use expression to show text, what do you mean? I kind of got confused there..

Comment: If you want to show the values of parameters selected by the user at run time in your report description you will need to write an expressions using values of that parameter. Which will change the report description depending on what type of data it is showing. If report always shows the same data then just use hardcoded values in textbox in your report heard or in tooltip option.

Comment: I basically need the description to display before the report is executed. The description is just to explain what the report does and there is only one parameter which is going to show data depending on that parameter. I am just having trouble how to display the description before running the report. Like you know how parameters display on the report before you hit view report? i want the description to be there so before user enter a parameter value, they will see what the report is about. The description will remain the same, there is not change.

Answer (score 0):

There is one ugly solution for this:
Set your parameter to default value which will hide all the tables and objects on your report when its run.
Put IF statements in your data sets which will produce only one row of default hard-coded data to execute the report - this should be in about one second after report is opened.
Create one object with the description of the report - for example txt box.
Add a expression to this object to be hidden if parameter value <> default value.
This will work but as I said - is a bit ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

Also:

1. You can put the description of the report in to new data set under field X.
2. Add New parameter which will be above your parameter.
3. Set default value as X from new data set to your new parameter.

This will display the information as it will execute first parameter before whole report will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a description on the deployed report on the report server?
Right click on the deployed report on the report server and click manage. In here there is a place to add a report description on how to run it and any text you want to enter

Answer (score 0):

> "that displays in the report before execution"

What exactly do you mean? If you do not execute the report you will not see the reports, so you will not see anything at all.

But Reports have a DESCRIPTION property. This is some text that is part of the reports meta information and visible in the list of reports in the report manager.