# In Microsoft Visual Studio IDE when generating an SSRS project, where do I find and set the report name for an .rdl file?

Tags: reporting-services

In Microsoft Visual Studio IDE when generating an SSRS project, where do I find and set the report name for an .rdl file? I think I should describe this question in detail.  I am not talking about the file name of the .rdl file.  The Database Manager who I have tasked with testing my first go with an SSRS report has emailed me:

"Would you please specify a report name (not DefaultReport) and the connection string that you are using?  We will have to connect the deployed report to a data connection.  Once deployed, we will send you the URL."

Maybe he means that I should name the file something other than DefaultReport.dll, or maybe there is a field somewhere that I can somehow set.  Is that the case/  I opened up the file in XML format and found at the start of the file an XML tag for  and so I added a field for "Name=..." there, but when I tried to display the file in "Design" mode, the visualizer threw an error and complained that "Name" was not a viable element for the "Report" item.

Comment: Can you post an image of the error?

Answer (score 1):

I believe they are asking about the Name Property in the Report Server. It's the Name of the report in the Report Server from the Name field of the ReportServer.dbo.Catalog table.

Visual Studio does not have a property for the Report Name. It uses the file name as the report name when deploying the file.

The property can be changed once the report is deployed to the report server.

[image]

The Description property **is** in Visual Studio and will populate the description text box. If there was a Name property in Visual Studio, it would appear in the same group as the Description.
[image]

Comment: All of what is said here is true about the [Report Name] on the report server web portal and in the ReportServer.dbo.Catalog table.  The [Report Description] can be adjusted as was mentioned in the post... but be aware that when you deploy a report with an *updated* Report Description, it will not update on the report server. You will have to do a manual update on the server.  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724177/add-ssrs-report-description/51047297#51047297 .  Thanks

Comment: @SherlockSpreadsheets - Ugh - good to know and yet kinda disappointing at the same time. Like the Chart visibility issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889385/ssrs-expression-will-not-affect-chart-title-visibility

Comment: Interesting.  I have never had to build graphs with SSRS, but I'm certain it would be a pain.  With PBIRS in SSRS2016, data visualization is now super easy with PBI. Have you tried that?  To add to your point... SSRS is a powerful tool but there are some *really* frustration bugs.  Particularly the Dataset Filter OR condition that we both posted about here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653422/ssrs-or-filter-logic-to-filter-from-and-in-operators/54207722#54207722.  I'm baffled that an enterprise reporting software from MSFT struggles with this use case.