# SSRS Expression will not affect chart title visibility

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to use an expression in the visibility tab of the Chart title properties window to hide the chart title based on a Boolean parameter. parameter will hide other parts of the chart, but will not hide the chart title.

I've tried using both switches, and IIF statements to verify that my code was working in other parts of the chart. I can hide the body, legend, and even the entire chart. Nothing I do will affect the chart title, however.

```
=IIF(Parameters!Visible.Value = FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

The chart title should no longer be visible, but instead remains visible and unaffected.

One work-around that I've used is to simply delete the chart title, and use a text box instead, which does react to the parameter's value, but I'm really wondering why I can't seem to get the chart title to hide based on the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You thought you were angry before - this seems to be yet another bug that will probably never be fixed.

The Chart Title Visibility works, if you **also** use a Boolean **True** or the same function for the Caption (the text display in the title). Ugh.

This Caption makes the Title invisible.

[image]

Maybe you can make this lameness work for you though - have the caption property be the title if visible or True if not:

```
=IIF(Parameters!Visible.Value = FALSE, "Caption Title", CBool(1))
```

Since every bug that I've cared about is Closed as Won't Fix or WAD, I wouldn't bother submitting this one to Microsoft. I know - it's so disappointing.