# SSRS: Custom report Code is not being called from Chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a Title on a Chart that I wish to be hidden in certain conditions.
I am trying to test the Code method:

```
Public Function TitleIsHidden() as Boolean
    Return True
End Function
```

I put this call:

```
=Code.TitleIsHidden()
```

into the Expression on the Visiblity property of the Title.

I also put this call into the Expression on the Visiblity property of a Textbox that is on the report (ie not in the Chart)

I Preview the report.

The Title is still visible

The Textbox is not visible

How do I call Report->Code methods from the Chart?

Answer (score 0):

Your code call is right. In all other cases this call will work, but not in this one. There is a bug with the title visibility, thus the call wont work.

You can try a workaround with a custom parameter. This post explains a good workaround:

[SSRS Expression will not affect chart title visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889385/ssrs-expression-will-not-affect-chart-title-visibility)